# Dynamic Word Document

Tags: database, dynamic, plugins, ms-word

Is it possible to have some data inside a word document that are being loaded from database?
Also editing in these data get reflected into database and vice versa. In other words can I use a MS Word as a desktop client to my database, and if so what is the required plugin/configurations/custom development to achieve this purpose

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is possible. To do this you would use VBA code. you can find some examples here.

[Pull data from Access database to Word document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20041895/pull-data-from-access-database-to-word-document)

http://windowssecrets.com/forums/showthread.php/154256-Extracting-data-from-an-Access-2010-database-using-Word-VBA

Note though that the method for connecting can change drastically based on what database you use.